# Input string was not in a correct format in vb,net

Tags: vb.net, label, double

I have an error problem in the text label. Is there another solution?

Thanks

```
 Private Sub CalculateGrandTotal()
            Dim tot As Double = 0
'error this below code 
            Dim cash As Double = Double.Parse(lblDisTotal.Text)
            For Each item As DataGridViewRow In grid.Rows
                tot += Double.Parse(item.Cells(5).Value.ToString())
            Next item
            lblGrandTotal.Text = (tot * (1 - cash / 100)).ToString("N2")
        End Sub
  Private Sub BtnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRefresh.Click
 lblDisTotal.Text = ""
        End Sub
```

Comment: use TryParse instead Parse as you can control the output for 'incorrect' values

Comment: Why would you need to get data from a `Label` in the first place? It's not like the user can enter data into it. Any data it displays, you must have put there in the first place. Wherever you got it from in the first place is the data you should be using. If the data is a number then it should already be in a numeric variable and you would then convert that to a `String` for display. If you then need to use the number, use the numeric variable.

Answer (score 0):

when the button event is refreshed then lblDisTotal does not become blank but becomes "0" then the problem is solved

```
 Private Sub CalculateGrandTotal()
            Dim tot As Double = 0
'error this below code 
            Dim cash As Double = Double.Parse(lblDisTotal.Text)
            For Each item As DataGridViewRow In grid.Rows
                tot += Double.Parse(item.Cells(5).Value.ToString())
            Next item
            lblGrandTotal.Text = (tot * (1 - cash / 100)).ToString("N2")
        End Sub
  Private Sub BtnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRefresh.Click
 lblDisTotal.Text = "0"
        End Sub
```

Comment: This would not guarantee resolution of the error. `lblDisTotal.Text` could be getting set to `""` in a number of other places in the code based on other events.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate solution would be [Double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-7.0#system-double-tryparse(system-string-system-double@)) to handle someone typing "hello world" into your text box if it is not sanitized.

As a rule, you should avoid .parse whereever possible and opt for try parse unless you can guarantee with absolute certainty that your value CAN be parsed into the type you want. Otherwise, utilize tryParse to prevent exceptions that can be prevented.

```
Private Sub CalculateGrandTotal()
    Dim tot As Double = 0
'error this below code 
    Dim cash As Double
    'tryParse returns a boolean indicating successful parsing. You can check for that, however, if it fails, it assigns 0 to your passed in double

    Double.TryParse(lblDisTotal.Text, cash)
    For Each item As DataGridViewRow In grid.Rows
        dim val as double
        Double.TryParse(item.Cells(5).Value, val)
        tot += val
    Next item
    lblGrandTotal.Text = (tot * (1 - cash / 100)).ToString("N2")
End Sub

Private Sub BtnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRefresh.Click
    lblDisTotal.Text = ""
End Sub
```